# Is possible product is checked "Subscription Product" field automatically create subscription?

Tags: web, odoo, subscription

Help I'm /website_sale module/ shopping subscription product. Then go to Website sale order. It's not create subscription. How to create automatically subscription in website module in odoo?

Answer (score 1):

You will achive this think with some customization
when your customer purchase product on your website and then after customer do payment then you will check the sale order state is 'sale' or 'done' and invoice is 'paid' if this condition satisfied then after you will create the "subscription.subscription"

In sale.order you can put this code in

```
@api.multi
def action_done(self):
```

Or

```
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
```

Or You can also use Write Method of sale order

```
@api.mulit
def write(self, values)
```